# Why does Java accept an actual string as an argument to a function that accepts a String object?

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have a function,

```java
String Greet(String a) {
    return a;
}
```

I can then call the function like so:

```java
Greet("str");
```

I have been writing Java for quite some time, but am embarassed to say that I never wondered about this.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: why would method `void foo (int arg)` accept 1 instead of an int variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an actual `String` (a `String` literal) is a `String` object reference. `"str".getClass()` is `java.lang.String` and `Object o = "str";` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 2):

From the Java Language Specification ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3)):

> String literals are references to instances of class `String`.